# Can nano detect file type without extension by the shebang to have proper syntax highlighting?

Tags: syntax-highlighting, shebang, nano

I see `nano` cannot detect a file type by a shebang (hashbang) line like

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
```

or similar.

Vim copes with this task w/o problems.

[image]

Is there a way to make it work for `nano`?

P.S. Created [github issue](https://github.com/madnight/nano/issues/1).

P.P.S. Even nano 4.2 version doesn't support this. (compiled from sources on CentOS7)

Answer (score 1):

There is a bug in nano syntax highlighting detection for .sh files, which I have found present in nano 4.8 and NOT present in nano 2.9.8, whereby a `#!` line with `/env` in it will not detect any shell except `sh`.

I have even found the specific commit which fixed it: https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/nano.git/commit/?id=6a3ba2ab501c138c7ee1e72d2a65cea77342a43c

Annoyingly, at time of writing this is affecting `.sh` color syntax highlighting in up-to-date nano from the package manager on up-to-date current LTS version of Ubuntu (20.04).

To fix it, you have to replace your `/usr/share/nano/sh.nanorc` with the same file from a newer (or older!) version of nano.

The current one from https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/nano.git/tree/syntax/sh.nanorc works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I've decided to make simple wrapper for that.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
####################################################
# Find file type and set syntax highlight for nano #
####################################################

set -o pipefail
set -o errexit
set -o nounset
#set -o xtrace

# Determine path to nano binary file
if [[ -f /usr/local/bin/nano ]]; then
  nano_bin=/usr/local/bin/nano
elif [[ -f /usr/bin/nano ]]; then
  nano_bin=/usr/bin/nano
else
  echo 'error: Sorry, nano binary file not found neither by path /usr/local/bin/nano nor /usr/bin/nano.' > /dev/stderr
  exit 2
fi

# check if syntax highlight argument already passed
if ! echo ${@} | grep -E '(-Y|--syntax)' > /dev/null; then
  # fetch interpreter name
  syntax_type=$(head -1 bin/cli | grep '#!' | awk '{match($0,"([a-z]+)$",a)}END{print a[0]}')

  if [[ -n "${syntax_type}" ]]; then
    # map a file interpreter onto syntax type like BASH into SH
    case "${syntax_type}" in
      bash)
        syntax_type=sh
        ;;
    esac

    nano_argument="--syntax=${syntax_type}"
  fi
fi

${nano_bin} ${nano_argument:-} ${@}
```

## Installation

### Simple option for `bash`

Copy the code into ~/.nano-wrap.sh

```
nano ~/.nano-wrap.sh
```

Add an alias into your `.bashrc` file:

```
echo 'alias nano="bash ~/.nano-wrap.sh" >> ~/.bashrc'
```

And reload it:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

J

Answer (score 0):

I've found that saving the file (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, type name, <kbd>Enter</kbd>) will cause `nano` to auto-detect the file type from the shebang and then syntax-highlight the file appropriately from then on.